# Desativar sequencia de input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom no exemplo que eu postei eu consigo desabilitar os input `valor1`, `vendedor1` e `supervisor1` ao marcar a opção `recalcular1`.

O problema e que tenho um formulário com vários input, e para evitar um código muito grande eu queria fazer o jqeury identificar o número do `checkbox` e desabilitar apenas os inputs do mesmo número.

Exemplo:
O `recalcular1` desabilita dos campos `valor1`, `vendedor1` e `supervisor1`.

O `recalcular2` desabilita dos campos `valor2`, `vendedor2` e `supervisor2`.

Alguém sabe uma forma prática de fazer isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#recalcular1").on("blur change", function() {

    // Verifica se exibe
    if ($("#recalcular1").is(':checked')) {
      $("#valor1").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#vendedor1").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#supervisor1").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#valor1").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#vendedor1").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#supervisor1").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular1' class='checkbox' name='recalcular1'>

<div>
  <input type='text' id='valor1' name='valor1'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor1' name='vendedor1'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor1' name='supervisor1'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd1' name='qtd1'>
</div>


<br><br>

<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular2' class='checkbox' name='recalcular2'>

<div>
  <input type='text' id='valor2' name='valor2'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor2' name='vendedor2'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor2' name='supervisor2'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd2' name='qtd2'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você puder alterar seu código html e envolver os `inputs` com uma `div` por exemplo, você poderá usar a função [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) do jquery para isso, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //classe do checkbox
  $(".checkbox").on("blur change", function () {         
        //se estiver marcado
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            //desabilita todos os "irmãos" do elemento
            $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled','disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' id='recalcular1' class='checkbox' name='recalcular1'>
  <input type='text' id='valor1' name='valor1'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor1' name='vendedor1'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor1' name='supervisor1'>
</div>

<div>
  <input type='checkbox' id='recalcular2' class='checkbox' name='recalcular2'>
  <input type='text' id='valor2' name='valor2'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor2' name='vendedor2'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor2' name='supervisor2'>
</div>
```

**EDIT: NOVA ESTRUTURA HTML ENVIADA PELO AP**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox").on("blur change", function() {
    
    $(this).next('div')//prox div
    .find('input:not(.qtd)')//busca input
    .prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));//desabilita se estiver marcado
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular1' class='checkbox' name='recalcular1'>

<div>
  <input type='text' id='valor1' name='valor1'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor1' name='vendedor1'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor1' name='supervisor1'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd1' class="qtd" name='qtd1'>
</div>


<br><br>

<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular2' class='checkbox' name='recalcular2'>

<div>
  <input type='text' id='valor2' name='valor2'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor2' name='vendedor2'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor2' name='supervisor2'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd2' class="qtd" name='qtd2'>
</div>
```

Outra opção é a de utilizar um atributo `data` para identificar os campos, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox").on("blur change", function() {   
    var dataInput = $(this).data('input');
    $('input[data-input="' + dataInput + '"]:not(.checkbox)').prop('disabled',$(this).is(':checked'));
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular1' data-input="ipt-1" class='checkbox' name='recalcular1'>

<div>
  <input type='text' id='valor1' data-input="ipt-1" name='valor1'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor1' data-input="ipt-1" name='vendedor1'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor1' data-input="ipt-1" name='supervisor1'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd1' class="qtd" name='qtd1'>
</div>


<br><br>

<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular2' class='checkbox' data-input="ipt-2" name='recalcular2'>

<div>
  <input type='text' id='valor2' data-input="ipt-2" name='valor2'>
  <input type='text' id='vendedor2' data-input="ipt-2" name='vendedor2'>
  <input type='text' id='supervisor2' data-input="ipt-2" name='supervisor2'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd2' class="qtd" name='qtd2'>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou legal sua solução, porém o meu `checkbox` não fica na mesma `div` que os `input`. Isso é uma coisa que não da para eu alterar.

Comment: @HugoBorges poste a estrutura do seu html, para ver se podemos ajudar.

Comment: Pronto, editei a resposta com um exemplo da minha estrutura html.

Comment: @HugoBorges veja minha edição se atende, você terá que verificar a próxima `div`, encontrar todos os inputs dentro dela excluindo o da quantidade, portanto precisará de uma classe neste campo.

Comment: Ficou bom, porém dessa forma eu fico amarrado ao layout, tem alguma forma de fazer isso usando um atributo? Tipo assim: `var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor"); 
            $("#" + inputValor).prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @HugoBorges você também pode fazer assim https://jsfiddle.net/8qz86skh/

Comment: Dessa forma ficou muito bom, obrigado. deu certo aqui

Answer (score 2):

Aproveitando a deixa do @LeandroSilva, acima, você pode simplificar o código guardando no checkbox o nome da classe dos campos que tem que desabilitar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var seletor = $(this).data("controles");
    $(seletor).prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular1' name='recalcular1' data-controles='.campos1'>

<div>
  <input type='text' class='campos1' id='valor1' name='valor1'>
  <input type='text' class='campos1' id='vendedor1' name='vendedor1'>
  <input type='text' class='campos1' id='supervisor1' name='supervisor1'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd1' name='qtd1'>
</div>


<br><br>

<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular2' name='recalcular2' data-controles='.campos2'>

<div>
  <input type='text' class='campos2' id='valor2' name='valor2'>
  <input type='text' class='campos2' id='vendedor2' name='vendedor2'>
  <input type='text' class='campos2' id='supervisor2' name='supervisor2'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd2' name='qtd2'>
</div>
```

Como você pode ver, criamos um atributo `data-controles` em cada *checkbox* com o seletor que seleciona os controles que têm que ser desabilitados quando aquela *checkbox* for marcada. O evento `change` de cada *checkbox* usa o `this` para pegar o seletor que lhe compete e desabilitar ou habilitar os controles que forem selecionados por aquele seletor.

Comment: Perfeito, simplificou bem o código.

Comment: @Wtrmute, ficou muito bom.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução possível também seria definir uma `class` para cada grupo de `inputs` e associá-la ao `ckeckbox` correspondente, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    // Grupo de campos 1
    if ($("#recalcular1").is(':checked')) {
      $(".campos1").prop('disabled', true);
    } 
    else {
      $(".campos1").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    // Grupo de campos 2
    if ($("#recalcular2").is(':checked')) {
      $(".campos2").prop('disabled', true);
    } 
    else {
      $(".campos2").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular1' name='recalcular1'>

<div>
  <input type='text' class='campos1' id='valor1' name='valor1'>
  <input type='text' class='campos1' id='vendedor1' name='vendedor1'>
  <input type='text' class='campos1' id='supervisor1' name='supervisor1'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd1' name='qtd1'>
</div>


<br><br>

<input type='checkbox' id='recalcular2' name='recalcular2'>

<div>
  <input type='text' class='campos2' id='valor2' name='valor2'>
  <input type='text' class='campos2' id='vendedor2' name='vendedor2'>
  <input type='text' class='campos2' id='supervisor2' name='supervisor2'>
  
  <!-- Não pode ficar desabilitado -->
  <input type='text' id='qtd2' name='qtd2'>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema e que meu formulário tem uns 30 campos, o jQuery ia ficar muito grande.